# sftp onto mac local machine from remote server

Tags: macos, ssh, file-transfer, sftp, hostname

Posted this on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231192/sftp-onto-mac-local-machine-from-remote-server) but that was deemed off topic so re-posting it here.

I am trying to download a dataset from a private remote server through *sftp* onto my local macbook pro machine. I was informed by the sys admin of the remote server to provide the following

1. IP address
2. login name
3. machine name (I think they mean hostname by this)

I found my login name using the `whoami` command, the IP (assuming that they want my public IP address) using the ifconfig command.

The machine name however is of the form `myname-MacBook-Pro.local`, is this what they mean by hostname? Is this information correct for me to provide them so I am able to download the data by sftp?

Also, I'm confused if the public IP of my machine is actually governed by the wi-fi network that I'm on? If so, I think I would have to be on the same network for which I provided the public IP, when I download the data, if not it won't work?

Any clarifications would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes hostname would be myname-MacBook-Pro.local   If you need a single ip for multiple locations consider a vpn and give the hostname and IP of the vpn endpoint (or the CIDR i.e. 173.x.x.x/24)

Answer (score 0):

Hostname is exactly what you think it is, yourname-MacBook-Pro. When you're in a terminal, you see it on every line. To get your public IP address go to http://www.whatismyip.com - Most likely the IP you see from ifconfig is a local IP set by your router. It probably starts with 192 or 172 which is local only.